# SP07 - How to get SPListItem Author and Last Editor

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, splistitem, caml, splistitemcollection

I want to get author and editor on SP `ListItem`:

**With this Page_load Code :**

```
SPQuery myQuery = new SPQuery();
myQuery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Text'>" + id + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

SPListItemCollection myItemCol = list.GetItems(myQuery);


foreach (SPListItem item in myItemCol)
{
    author = item["Author"].ToString();
    editor = item["Editor"].ToString();
}

this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p>" + "Created by : " + author + "</p>"));
this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p>" + "Edited by: " + editor + "</p>"));
```

**Result is :**

[image]

When Another user edit an item :
`Created by` must change. I want "Created by" to be a static data.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Created by never changes for an specific item.

Comment: Where i update a listItem created by must change :{

Comment: Why must change?

Comment: Do you want to change the created by column using code in c#? as it will not change while updating the item information. Correct information from jpuddacq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author is the person who created the item. It is assigned once the item is created and never changed. 
Editor is changed every time item is modified.

Better use `SPFieldUserValue` to retrieve `SPUser`.

```
foreach (SPListItem item in myItemCol)
{
    SPFieldUserValue usrAuthor = new SPFieldUserValue(SPContext.Current.Web, item["Author"].ToString());
author = usrAuthor.User.Name;
    }
```

Comment: I'll try now....

Comment: thank you...What is 96;# ? how to remove this ?